# Send data to specific client in Asynchronous Socket

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I use from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example?redirectedfrom=MSDN) Microsoft example for Asynchronous Server Socket that server has many clients, this example works correctly, client send data and server run  ReadCallback function and at the ***same time*** server can reply to this client (just can send data when received data), my question is :

> server how to send data to a specific client **at another time** that hasn't data from clinet?(when server want to send data to a specific client)
>   how can i save connected client and send data to one of them at another time ?(assuming that client connected)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

// State object for reading client data asynchronously  
public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    // Thread signal.  
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static List<Socket> Connections = new List<Socket>();
    public AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {
    }

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
        // The DNS name of the computer  
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".  
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[4];

        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1111);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Console.WriteLine(ipAddress.AddressFamily);
        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(1000);
            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                allDone.Reset();
                //Console.WriteLine(ipAddress.);
                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  

                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.  
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.  
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;


        //Connections.Add(listener); Thats my try !!!
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket.
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read
            // more data.  
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("\r") > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the
                // client. Display it on the console.  
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                    content.Length, content);
                // Echo the data back to the client.  
                Send(handler, content);
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.  
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        //await StartListening();
        //Thread thread = new Thread();
        //thread.Start();
        new Thread(delegate () {
            StartListening();
        }).Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connections Number : " + Connections.Count.ToString());
            foreach (var item in Connections)
            {
                **Send(item, "I'm Server !");**  i want to send this message
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you accept the connection, save the socket in a list.
You can access the list at any time and get the socket you want.

Comment: I did it before, but on list socket connection state is close  and the connection is a read-only property on the socket and Does not fit on the same connection